# "No database selected" no PHP com MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Colunas a receberem dados:

```
$GravaLinhaBanco = "INSERT INTO `trechosmonitora_cotacao` (`Codigo`, `CodTrecho`, `CodCliente`, `CodLoja`, `Url`, `Rotulo`, `Trecho`, ";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "`Origem`, `Destino`, `Tipo`, `Status`, `IdaVolta`, `Antecedencia`, `Permanencia`, `Adultos`, `Criancas`,";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . " `Bebes`, `ServidorMonitorando`, `SituacaoMonitoramento`, `Data_Monitoramento`, `Data_Monitorado`, ";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "`Hora_Inicio`, `Hora_Fim`, `TrackTrechos`, `VooaVoo`, `TarifaCompleta`)";
#DADOS A SEREM GRAVADOS;
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "VALUES('".$codigo."', '".$codTrecho."', '".$codcliente."', '".$codigosite."', '".$url."', '".$rotulo."',";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "'".$trecho."', '".$codorigem."', '".$coddestino."', '".$tipoVoo."', '".$status."', '".$idavolta."', '".$anoantecedencia."',";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "'".$permanencia."', '".$adultos."', '".$criancas."', '".$bebes."', '', '0', '00/00/0000', '00/00/0000', '00:00:00', '00:00:00',";
$GravaLinhaBanco = $GravaLinhaBanco . "'".$TrackTrechos."', 'N', 'S');";
$sql = $GravaLinhaBanco;
$codigo = $codigo + 1;

$NewQuery = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$NewQuery = mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Gustavo o erro acontece antes desse código que tu postou, como tu está executando a conexão com o Banco?

Comment: @Gustavo, o erro indica que está faltando selecionar a base de dados. após utilizar a função mysqli_connect, utilize a mysqli_select_db

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, por favor, marque como sendo a resposta correta.

Answer (score 2):

O erro `No database selected` ocorre pois não foi selecionado uma base de dados para operar.

Você pode selecionar um banco de duas formas distintas.

Selecionando na hora de conectar:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
```

ou após conectar:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha');
mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'banco');
```